# JSP - Write text file to users c drive

Tags: jsp, client

I need to write a text file to a users C drive using JSP, is this possible, I need to do this to check if the user has admin rights.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which C drive are you talking about ? Is it of server o client. If client then how can you be sure that client is going to be on windows only ?

Comment: After finding out it is not possible to write a file onto a windows users C drive using JSP (I'm still new to JSP and unaware of its capabilities), I looked at applets and found that it is possible to create an applet which writes a file onto a windows clients C drive just as long as it's self signed, it will just prompt the user for permission. More so, you don't even need the user’s permission if the applet is signed by VeriSign. This is my solution :)

Answer (score 2):

No. JSP runs on the server and cannot instruct browsers to read or write from arbitrary files on the client system. That would be a serious security risk.

Comment: Cheers for the response, I'm new to jsp.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, I'm still new to JSP but I found a solution which is to use an applet which allows me to write to a clients C drive.

Comment: That isn't using JSP. That is using an applet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, web applications do not have access to the client machines for security reasons.

Comment: After doing some research I found it is possible to do using an applet as long as it's signed: This helped me learn how to sign an applet: http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm

Answer (score 0):

When a web page can write files on a user's machine through the browser, it's called a critical security issue.

Comment: Even through a signed applet?

Comment: No, but that's not a JSP page, that's an Applet. There are many other technologies that allow writing on the client's machine from the browser: Applets, Flash, ActiveX, browser extensions...

Comment: Cheers, I'll look at applets.